# Windows Presentation Foundation Adaptive Application

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am new to WPF, i need to know, is it possible to make WPF application responsive, if so, how ?

What i meant with responsive is, all content and controls resize with window resizing accordingly.

Comment: Too broad, and wrong terminology in the title. Yes, you can make a WPF GUI adapt to the screen size, in various ways. But how big do you want your TextBoxes to get?

Answer (score 0):

This is an extremely general question. The answer would most likely end up being a WPF tutorial, which there are already plenty of. 
For your needs, my advice would be to check out the layout system, if you use the correct layouts in the correct spots, your content will resize as you wish. 
This link helped me a lot when I started WPF : [WPF tutorial #layouts](https://www.wpftutorial.net/Layout.html)
Its content is limited, so you'll want to look somewhere else eventually, but it does a good job of giving an overview of what is available.
The ones that are most usefull for me are Grid Panel & Dock Panel, ocasionnaly the Stack Panel. Viewbox is usefull for more control on resizing content. 
 
Hope this helps, good luck.